# Why does the code not run in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I got the easy code, which runs here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN9PAQGSYPI5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<p> price in usd: <input type=text id="price" name="price" onChange="calc()"></p>
<p>Brutto: <input type=number id="brutto" name="brutto"></p>
<script>
function calc() {
  document.getElementById("brutto").value = 1.2 * document.getElementById("price").value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the code not run in my popup.html? It is not possible to ru onChange events in an extension?

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<p> price in usd: <input type=text id="price" name="price" onChange="calc()"></p>
<p>Brutto: <input type=number id="brutto" name="brutto"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function calc() {
  document.getElementById("brutto").value = 1.2 * document.getElementById("price").value;
}
```

Comment: Why is there closing `</body` and `</html>` tags at the beginning of the code?

Comment: All JavaScript in a popup has to be referenced in a separate .js file

Comment: I had it in a popup.js file, but didnt work either, and it was a copy and paste error, sorry.

Comment: Any errors in the dev console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont call function from HTML due to content security policy.

Bind event "change" using jquery/javascript after page is load. please see following example which I have made for you   using jquery.

**popup.js**

```
$(function(){
$("#price").change(function(){
    calc();
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
});

function calc() {
  document.getElementById("brutto").value = 1.2 * document.getElementById("price").value;
}
```

**Note**

> Make sure Jquery must in popup.html